# How to create and test a gem with Rspec and Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rubygems

I have created a model that I use across applications.

```
module WeblabOnRails
  class TimeOnly
    #...
  end
end
```

I put the code in my `lib/weblab_on_rails/time_only.rb` and I invoke it, each time from `application.rb`.

I would like to integrate that code into a gem and write tests using Rspec and Cucumber. I am using Rails 3.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using bundler to create and publish gems. Check out this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler. Once you created your gem project you can  use RSpec, Cucumber or whatever to test it.

Comment: I have already stumbled across that RailsCast, but it seems like covering just the basics. I would like to know how people code a gem and how they transform their code into gems and test them.